# Required type: java.lang.String Provided: java.lang.String

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

[The required and provided data types are the same i.e.,
**java.lang.String** then why is this error being shown?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWS3B.png)

[This is my project configuration.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfP1a.png)

[These were the default dependencies in my project. In specifications tab only one depenedency of **Servlet (5.0.0)** was included.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AntZt.png)

Given that the required and provided data types are the same, there shouldn't have been any problem. If someone can help it would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In IntelliJ, go to

**File -> Invalidate Caches... -> Invalidate & restart**.

(All checkboxes in "Invalidate Caches" were unchecked, and I just clicked "Invalidate & restart", and it worked for me.)

IntelliJ restarts and the issue is now fixed. ✅